# Rails - insert many random items on create with has_many_through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I want to create a random pack of 15 cards which should be invoked in the cardpacks_controller on create. I have the following models:

Card:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  # relations
  has_many :cardpacks, through: :cardpackcards
  belongs_to :cardset
end
```

Cardpack:

```
class Cardpack < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relations
  has_many :cards, through: :cardpackcards
  belongs_to :cardset

  # accept attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards
end
```

Cardpackcards:

```
class Cardpackcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relations
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :cardpack
end
```

Cardsets:

```
class Cardset < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relations
  has_many :cards
  has_many :cardsets
end
```

How can I create 15 Cardpackcards records with random card_id values and with the same cardpack_id (so they belong to the same pack)

I have watched the [complex form series](http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1) tutorial but it gives me no comprehension as how to tackle this problem.

I hope anyone can help me solve this problem and give me more insight in the rails language.

Thanks,
Erik

Comment: Do the "random card_id" values exist already or are you asking how to create them at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database system you might be able to use an order random clause to find 15 random records. For example, in Postgres:

```
Model.order("RANDOM()").limit(15)
```

Given the random models, you can add a `before_create` method that will setup the associations.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Cardpackcard` model doesn't do anything but provide a matching between `cards` and `cardpacks`, you could use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association instead, which would simplify things a bit.

Without it, the controller code might look something like this:

```
cardset  = Cardset.find(params[:cardset_id])
cardpack = Cardpack.create(:cardset => cardset)

15.times do
  cardpack.cardpackcards.create(:card => Card.create(:cardset => cardset))
end
```

Comment: Hi, tnx a lot I have changed the create to build so the id's were set and everything works like a charm (except for the random but i'll fix that)

my result:

`@cardpack = Cardpack.new(params[:cardpack])
  
    15.times do
      randomcard = Card.all(order: 'RANDOM()', limit: 1);
      @cardpack.cardpackcards.build(:card => randomcard.last)
    end`

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand what you want. You could use 
`randomcard = Card.order("RANDOM()").first` 
for more efficiency.